# Do key signatures indicate changes in tablature fret numbers?

Tags: sheet-music, key-signatures, tablature

I have a tab book for "Black Sabbath" and the song "Iron Man" for example, it has a key signature of `bbb`. I know this song is played in standard E tuning, and eg the main riff starts with a B + F# power chord on fret 2 string 5. However, the book I have seems to have all the fret numbers bumped by 1, as though the guitar were downtuned a half-step.

Is it normal for key signature changes to modify what a tablature shows, or is this tab book wrong?

The book is "Black Sabbath Anthology" ISBN-13: 978-0-8256-1084-4 by Amsco Publications, for reference; attached is a photo of the 1st page.

[image: Black Sabbath - Iron Man]

Comment: I think you mean three flats (not 'bbb'), which is the key of Eb major/C minor. Starting the riff on the third fret of that string (C) is appropriate for that key signature. If the song is actually in another key (regardless of how close it is to Eb/Cm), then the tab will change.

Comment: Most songs can be played in multiple places in the same key.  Also, the guitar can be tuned differently thus making the true notes map to different frets than you are used to.

Comment: Yes 3 flats... but I know this song is played in standard E tuning so that's where I get confused. There's nothing to indicate downtuning in the tab.

Comment: The version of the main riff in your book clearly doesn't start with "a B + D power chord".

Comment: Yes sorry I meant `B+F#` (str 5 fr 2, st 4 fr 4), but it's indicating `C+G` (str 5 fr 3, st 4 fr 5). The song is definitely played in the former. The tab is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Tab in itself has no direct reference to keys, key signatures or note names. There no need. It purely tells the reader where, on which fret of which string, to place fingers.

The key itself is a separate entity, and if a key changes, or there's an accidental note, it's shown directly as a different number , maybe on a different string, in the tab.

The factor to watch is the letter names at the beginning of the tab - not always EADGBe, or sometimes the legend - 'tune down a semitone to Eb', etc,

Better quality tab will have a stave as well, which helps with timing, and can occasionally clarify discrepancies in tab numbers.

Comment: There is nothing to indicate downtuning.

Comment: That doesn't mean a great deal.  Tab is sometimes not as good or as accurate as it should be, and things like the band has downtuned might miss the tab writer's attention. Reference to the original track is the best solution, and working things out without relying on possibly unreliable tab will benefit in the future.

Comment: So the tab is wrong?

Comment: Now that it's visible - no.

Comment: But it's literally the wrong note at those frets in standard tuning. I'm also confused: at the top of the tab it has chord description; the F5 shows the root note on fret 9 (indicating downtuning half a step), but the E5 root note is fret 7 (indicating normal tuning).

Comment: At the top, the chord windows, there is a space after the E chord. My guess is there should be a flat sign between the E and the 5. The F5 is shown on fret 8. Damn! My flat signing doesn't work in comments!!

Comment: The first fret shown in the diagram is fret 8, but the one indicating the root note is 9. Still, a missing `#` makes sense in the `E#5` and would indicate the guitar is downtuned.

Comment: There's a 2 fret difference, and there's a 2 fret difference between F and **Eb**.